# TabView in SwiftUI that doesn’t change view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible to include a TabView in SwiftUI that doesn’t change views? I need a bottom menu bar that has 4 items in, but these items do not all need to move to a new view.  Can I change the expected behaviour of TabView and utilise the buttons it provides or do I need to just make my own?

Comment: this is certainly possible, however it is not he inteded use of a TabBar. 
I would recommend making your own custom TabBar

Comment: I thought as much and feels like the best approach, I just didn’t want to reinvent the wheel if i didn’t need to. 

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the newest beta (2020), you could use a `toolbar`.

On iOS you can set the placement of the a `ToolbarItem` as the bottom bar, and make look similar to a bottom tab bar. Back in UIKit you would probably have used a `toolbar` as well, since `TabBar`s are associated with navigation.

Anyway, here's an example:

```
HStack {
    ForEach(1..<5) { number in
      Text("\(number)")
    }
}
.toolbar(items: {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
      Button("Test", action: {})
    }
})
```

Add a `toolbar` modifier to your view, then add the items with whatever content you want. Since the `ToolbarItem` uses a view builder, you can give it any view.

If you want multiple buttons spread out nicely, replace the `Button` inside the `ToolbarItem` with an `HStack` and have multiple buttons/spacers/whatever you need to get the layout you want.

**Note:** the `.bottomBar` placement might not be available on all platforms

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I’ll look at this today.  So far I’ve used a zstack with a background then a hstack with 4 buttons with their frames max width / height set to infinity to evenly size and space them.  But this might be a better option